# Implement push notification server in php

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

This is my first post, sorry my English

Hello every one. I am a new programmer in PHP and i would like to use Zend Mobile Framework to implement my push notificator server.

I'm searching how to implement the tomcat project used in

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html

but written in PHP.

In the code most below I written the used sources. 
When I call the submit button,  always have response with InvalidRegistration error.

Can anyone see where the error?

Thank You very much

http://pastebin.com/MauzLX71

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things that you are likely having happen here is the following:

- Your code is actually processing and attempting to send a message prior to your call of sendPush which may be causing part of the issue.

  - I've modified the code and had put the registration id in there: http://pastebin.com/NhrD5N6i
- Did you sign up for an API key and replace that portion in the code?
- In the demo client application; it shows how to actually leverage the registration; see my comment on the following GitHub issue: https://github.com/mwillbanks/Zend_Mobile/issues/16

  - Your server needs to have the registration id from the device; this is likely what you do not have.
  - One way of getting the registration ID is on the onRegistered call inside the client app, do a Log.i("MY_APP_TAG", regId); then look at the logcat output.

*Android Example*

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(Constants.SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String regId) {
        Log.i("MY_APP_TAG", "Registered: " + regId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String regId) {
        // write a call here to send the regId to your server and unregister it
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("MY_APP_TAG", "Received message!");
        // grabbing data looks like the following; the assumption
        // is title is part of the data string.
        String title = intent.getExtras().getString("title");
    }

}
```

*Zend_Mobile_Push_Gcm Example*

See the updated link (http://pastebin.com/NhrD5N6i) I provided of your pasted code; you will want to use the registration ID above in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

According with Android GCM's architectural overview you have an invalidRegistration error when:

> Invalid Registration ID Check the formatting of the registration ID
>   that you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration ID
>   the phone receives in the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
>   intent and that you're not truncating it or adding additional
>   characters.  Happens when error code is **InvalidRegistration**.

Check the official GCM documentaion [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html), please.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I don't Store the registration ID. That is necessary. I write all code and refactor it, when I achieve that I will post the whole solution. Thank you.